# Macro will work in developer and with hot key but not with button... any idea why?

Tags: excel, vba

As mentioned above, the code works just fine both in the developer and with the hot keys but when I use the button, it seems like the "go to last row + 1" doesn't work. When I select the button, the data keeps being copied and recopied into row 2.

```
Sub Entry_Schedule()
' Entry_Schedule Macro
    Dim FrstEmptCll As Range
    FrstEmtCll = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D4:I4").Copy
    Sheets("Data").Range("A" & FrstEmtCll + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
   End Sub
```

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you mean by button? Is it a button on a userform, an ActiveX command button, a form control button? Then also, what exactly have to tried with the button itself? We probably need to see the code for the button rather than this.

Comment: And _"...it seems like the 'go to last row + 1' doesn't work"_ isn't listed anywhere in your provided code.

Comment: Form Control.  I don't have a code for the button, I just linked it to the code mentioned above.  Sheets("Data").Range("A" & FrstEmtCll + 1).... is what I was referencing with the "go to last row + 1"

Comment: So, I am assuming that this "button" is on another sheet, right? Because `Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` isn't qualified with a worksheet. You did good and qualified the next two range objects with sheets `Sheet2` and `Data`, but didn't qualify the range you are having issues with.

Comment: Affirmative.  The "button" and to-be copied cells are on Sheets("Sheet2") while the list that I'm trying to paste to is on sheets("Data").  I thought that since I started the line with Sheets("Data")... it would paste in the Sheets("Data") tab.

Comment: You are counting the rows from whatever sheet you are currently on. It has nothing to do with the next two lines, it's drawn off the `ActiveSheet` object since you didn't specify otherwise.

Comment: that was the problem! thanks!

Comment: @B-Rye Please have a look at my answer. There are more issues in your code than that!

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs did you close vote for typographical error? This is much more than a typo (see my answer). Please don't close vote for that.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I have retracted my flag, but can't do anything about the one who flagged before I did (No MCVE I believe it was).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to qualify **every** Range, Rows, Columns, etc with a worksheet:

```
FrstEmtCll = Worksheets("Data").Range("A" & Worksheets("Data").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

The second issue is that you declare `Dim FrstEmptCll As Range` but you try to put the row number into a range object `.End(xlUp).Row`.

So either `Set` the range to the cell and offset:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Entry_Schedule()
    ' Entry_Schedule Macro
    Dim FrstEmtCll As Range
    Set FrstEmtCll = Worksheets("Data").Range("A" & Worksheets("Data").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(RowOffset:=1)
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D4:I4").Copy
    FrstEmtCll.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Or use the row number (as `Long`):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Entry_Schedule()
    ' Entry_Schedule Macro
    Dim FrstEmptRow As Long
    FrstEmptRow = Worksheets("Data").Range("A" & Worksheets("Data").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D4:I4").Copy
    Worksheets("Data").Range("A" & FrstEmptRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

---

Additionally you mistyped your variable name `FrstEmptCll` vs `FrstEmtCll` (missing `p`). This means you actually have 2 different variables now (which easily blows up your code). To avoid such errors I highly recommend to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*.

Comment: This is very good advice. Thank you. I'm new to VBA so I've got a lot of catching up to do.

Comment: @B-Rye Especially if you are new to VBA `Option Explicit` forces you to write good code and prevents you from running into errors.